# Unable to install any version of Angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

I am unable to install the Angular CLI after completing the pre-requisite. My node and npm version is v16.2.0 and 8.1.4 respectively. Image attached for reference

[image]

The error I am receiving is
[image]

What I have tried

1. Fresh node installation version 16.3.1 (LTS)
2. Downgrading Node version up to 12
3. npm cache clean --force
4. npm install -g @angular/cli --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
5. Uninstalling and npm i -g @angular/cli --force
6. Cross check the node environment variables
7. Tried restarting the system

Comment: Is that a screenshot of the Windows console? Have you tried installing from the PowerShell?

Comment: @GOTO0 yes, I will give it a try with PowerShell.